# MySQL select first five unique rows depending on two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table which have two columns for selecting propouses - tablica and contentid [as it shows here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8BOn.png)

[image]

i want to select first five rows sorted by date DESC which have unique combination of both columns - tablica and contentid

how that can happend? I've tried already with combinations of distinct, group_concat and concat but everything i've tried skip some of the rows.

please help.

Comment: if you post the SQL queries you are trying then we may be able to correct them for you. Also, if you post an example of the output you are expecting to see then it will give people further clarity in what you are trying to achieve

Comment: this will work `SELECT DISTINCT tablica, contentid FROM table_name ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5;` but if you add another column in the select it wont work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello_ mate

If you don't need other stuff than those two fields you can use the query I did post in the comments below your question.

Otherwise if you need all the fields you can use this query:

```
SELECT `id`, `tablica`, `contentid`, `ip`, `userid`, MAX(date) as `date` 
FROM test2 
GROUP BY tablica, contentid 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

using the `MAX` function we select the latest matching date for this `tablica` and `contentid`, if you want to get oldest date use `MIN` function

Let me know if this works for you.

Good Luck!

Comment: Great! I'm glad that this was helpful :)